# How to record (photos and videos) directly to Samsung's Secure Folder?

Tags: samsung, hidden

Sometimes or usually I need to take photos or videos of my documentation with my Samsung mobile.

How do I configure Secure Folder (provided by Samsung) to record all I want directly into Secure Folder? I don't want to move them one by one manually.

[image: Samsung Secure Folder app icon]

Answer (score 1):

You can log into Secure Folder before you take any photos and videos. Use the Camera that's inside of the Secure Folder. If it's not there, tap "Add apps" and add it.

You can also do this with a lot of other apps, it's kind of like having a second phone inside your phone but more secure.